# How to remove all future notifications scheduled by my app?

Tags: uwp

I find the samples in Microsoft document about how to [remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotifier.removefromschedule?view=winrt-19041) a future scheduled toast notification if it matches a condition. Is there any method to remove all future scheduled toast notifications of my app, regardless of any tag or group?

```
var notifier = Notifications.ToastNotificationManager.createToastNotifier();
var scheduled = notifier.getScheduledToastNotifications();                    

for (var i = 0, len = scheduled.length; i < len; i++) {
    
    // The itemId value is the unique ScheduledTileNotification.Id assigned to the 
    // notification when it was created.
    if (scheduled[i].id === itemId) {
        notifier.removeFromSchedule(scheduled[i]);
    }
}
```

Currently, I am removing all future notifications by iterating through a loop, which takes more seconds. I want to know, whether there is a method to remove all future notifications of my app with a single method or with any other best short way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use [ToastNotificationHistory.Clear()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.notifications.toastnotificationhistory.clear?view=winrt-19041) to remove all the sent notifications. But there is no native API to remove all scheduled notifications. The code you use might be a better way.

Comment: Thanks. Though there is no way than accepting this behavior, it really seems an inefficient way, since it causes a noticeable delay in removing them. Microsoft could have provided a method like RemoveAll() like ToastNotificationHistory.Clear()

Comment: Yes, no other way to do that. You could submit a feature request in the Feedback Hub about this. You could find the Feedback Hub in the start menu.